# how to add exclude svn directories back under revision control

Tags: svn

We update our webservers with SVN changes,  at some I removed certain directories from being versioned so when I do an svn status I get the following

```
svn status /srv/data/
?       /srv/data/dir1
?       /srv/data/dir2
```

Im trying to add Dir1   back so its get updated on an svn up command.  Ive tried to an svn add --force /srv/data/dir1 and then a commit,  I see the files added and committed but still the svn status doesn't reflect the change and i don't get updated files on svn up.

How do I get the server to see this directory to be versioned